# Passenger + Nginx + Node (Meteor) 100% CPU usage

Tags: node.js, meteor, nginx, passenger, cpu-usage

I have a Meteor app deployed with Passenger + Nginx (as [follow](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/aws/integration_mode.html)) on AWS EC2 instance under Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64)

The problem is that it takes around 100% CPU usage permanently.

[image]

I've tried to switch to more powerful instance and even deployed a blank app instead of mine - still the same.

Any ideas where to dig?
Thanks.

P.S.

var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2017/02/08 08:04:20 [info] 18232#18232: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71
[ 2017-02-08 08:04:20.4123 18239/7fe378ac0780 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1281 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2017-02-08 08:04:20.4281 18242/7f7adea7b780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1070 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2017-02-08 08:04:20.4282 18242/7f7adea7b780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:245 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2017-02-08 08:04:20.4309 18242/7f7adea7b780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:820 ]: Passenger core online, PID 18242
[ 2017-02-08 08:04:20.4511 18248/7fdc44af6780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2017-02-08 08:04:20.4517 18248/7fdc44af6780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 18248
[ 2017-02-08 08:04:22.7236 18242/7f7ade98c700 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:464 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

npm install output:

```
> fibers@1.0.15 install /var/www/play/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

`linux-x64-48` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install /var/www/play/bundle/programs/server
> node npm-rebuild.js

{
  "meteor-dev-bundle": "0.0.0",
  "npm": "3.10.10",
  "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",
  "http_parser": "2.7.0",
  "icu": "56.1",
  "modules": "48",
  "node": "6.9.5",
  "openssl": "1.0.2k",
  "uv": "1.9.1",
  "v8": "5.1.281.89",
  "zlib": "1.2.8"
}
meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 /var/www/play/bundle/programs/server
├── amdefine@1.0.1
├── asap@2.0.5
├── fibers@1.0.15
├── meteor-promise@0.8.0
├─┬ node-gyp@3.4.0
│ ├─┬ fstream@1.0.10
│ │ └── inherits@2.0.3
│ ├─┬ glob@7.1.1
│ │ ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6
│ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
│ │ ├── once@1.4.0
│ │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1
│ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.11
│ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.3
│ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6
│ │   ├── balanced-match@0.4.2
│ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ ├─┬ nopt@3.0.6
│ │ └── abbrev@1.0.9
│ ├─┬ npmlog@3.1.2
│ │ ├─┬ are-we-there-yet@1.1.2
│ │ │ ├── delegates@1.0.0
│ │ │ └── readable-stream@2.2.2
│ │ ├── console-control-strings@1.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ gauge@2.6.0
│ │ │ ├── aproba@1.1.0
│ │ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
│ │ │ ├── has-unicode@2.0.1
│ │ │ ├── object-assign@4.1.1
│ │ │ ├── signal-exit@3.0.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ string-width@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├── code-point-at@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ └─┬ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
│ │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1
│ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1
│ │ │ └── wide-align@1.1.0
│ │ └── set-blocking@2.0.0
│ ├─┬ osenv@0.1.4
│ │ ├── os-homedir@1.0.2
│ │ └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2
│ ├─┬ path-array@1.0.1
│ │ └─┬ array-index@1.0.0
│ │   ├─┬ debug@2.6.0
│ │   │ └── ms@0.7.2
│ │   └─┬ es6-symbol@3.1.0
│ │     ├── d@0.1.1
│ │     └─┬ es5-ext@0.10.12
│ │       └── es6-iterator@2.0.0
│ ├─┬ request@2.79.0
│ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0
│ │ ├── aws4@1.6.0
│ │ ├── caseless@0.11.0
│ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5
│ │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0
│ │ ├── extend@3.0.0
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@2.1.2
│ │ │ └── asynckit@0.4.0
│ │ ├─┬ har-validator@2.0.6
│ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
│ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
│ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
│ │ │ │ ├── has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ commander@2.9.0
│ │ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ is-my-json-valid@2.15.0
│ │ │ │ ├── generate-function@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ generate-object-property@1.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── is-property@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├── jsonpointer@4.0.1
│ │ │ │ └── xtend@4.0.1
│ │ │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.1
│ │ │   └── pinkie@2.0.4
│ │ ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3
│ │ │ ├── boom@2.10.1
│ │ │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5
│ │ │ ├── hoek@2.16.3
│ │ │ └── sntp@1.0.9
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1
│ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.3.1
│ │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.3
│ │ │ │ └── verror@1.3.6
│ │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.10.2
│ │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3
│ │ │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0
│ │ │   ├── bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.1
│ │ │   ├─┬ dashdash@1.14.1
│ │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0
│ │ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1
│ │ │   ├─┬ getpass@0.1.6
│ │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0
│ │ │   ├── jodid25519@1.0.2
│ │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.0
│ │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.14.5
│ │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0
│ │ ├── isstream@0.1.2
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.14
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.26.0
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2
│ │ ├── qs@6.3.0
│ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@2.3.2
│ │ │ └── punycode@1.4.1
│ │ ├── tunnel-agent@0.4.3
│ │ └── uuid@3.0.1
│ ├── rimraf@2.5.4
│ ├─┬ tar@2.2.1
│ │ └── block-stream@0.0.9
│ └─┬ which@1.2.12
│   └── isexe@1.1.2
├─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.6.29
│ ├─┬ rc@1.1.6
│ │ ├── deep-extend@0.4.1
│ │ ├── ini@1.3.4
│ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0
│ │ └── strip-json-comments@1.0.4
│ ├── semver@5.2.0
│ └─┬ tar-pack@3.1.4
│   ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│   │ └── ms@0.7.1
│   ├── fstream-ignore@1.0.5
│   ├── once@1.3.3
│   ├─┬ readable-stream@2.1.5
│   │ ├── buffer-shims@1.0.0
│   │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
│   │ ├── isarray@1.0.0
│   │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7
│   │ ├── string_decoder@0.10.31
│   │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
│   └── uid-number@0.0.6
├── promise@7.1.1
├── semver@4.1.0
├── source-map@0.1.32
├── source-map-support@0.3.2
└── underscore@1.5.2

npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
```

Comment: You can start by ssh'ing into the box, and running the `top` command to see which process is taking all the cpu

Comment: It's "Passenger NodeA". (screenshot added)

Comment: Any entries in the log files to give you a clue? Did the npm install work properly?

Comment: nginx error log and npm install output added. By the way, in dev mode (without passenger+nginx) everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Meteor deployment guide](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment), you have to use specifically Node 4.6.2.

> Depending on the version of Meteor you are using, you should install
> the proper version of node using the appropriate installation process
> for your platform.
>
> - Node 4.6.2 for Meteor 1.4.x
> - Node 0.10.43 for Meteor 1.3.x and earlier
>
> If you use a mismatched version of Node when deploying your
> application, you will encounter errors!

[Passenger docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/aws/nginx/oss/install_language_runtime.html) also suggest a 4.x version of node.

It worked for me with node js v4.8.4. Now CPU rarely goes above 10%.

Comment: I've been suggested this on Meteor forum, trouble appeared again. Looks like my app just needed more powerful instance. Anyway, thanks )

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by reinstalling everything from the scratch. Still don't know what happend.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening again, approximately once per day:
[image]

Wonder if there is some alternative for Passenger + Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Node version as mentioned in above answers strictly matters. You can try installing nginx+ pm2. It works like charm. To know more about pm2 , I already answered here.

[How to run built of Meteor's sample app via Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589278/how-to-run-built-of-meteors-sample-app-via-node/45606882#45606882)